# Determining whether a type is a class type?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, type-traits, partial-specialization

In Chapter 19.8.4 of the book "C++ Templates - The Complete Guide - Second Edition", the authors show how one can determine if a type is a class type in compile-time:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename = void_t<>>
struct IsClass : false_type { };

template <typename T>
struct IsClass<T, void_t<int T::*>> : true_type { };

int main()
{
    struct S { };
    cout << IsClass<S>::value; // prints 1
}
```

This paragraph explains how the partial specialization detects a class type:

> ... only class types can be used as the basis of pointer-to-member types. That is, in a type construct of the form `X Y::*`, `Y` can only be a class type. The following formulation of `IsClass<T>` exploits the property (and picks `int` arbitrarily for type `X`)

What I don't understand is why picking `int` as `X` works, even if we test `IsClass<>` with a struct `S` that has no members at all (It also works for class types having a member other than `int`)

Comment: Class does not need to have members to declare a pointer to member type. It is similar to not having a function not preventing from declaring a pointer to function type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short, it's because the standard says so.

According to [[dcl.mptr]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.mptr#2) (I'm including only the relevant parts here):

> [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> struct X {
>   int a;
> };
> struct Y;
>
> double X::* pmd;
> char Y::* pmc;
> ```
>
> . . .
>   The declaration of `pmd` is well-formed even though `X` has no members of type `double`. Similarly, the declaration of `pmc` is well-formed even though `Y` is an incomplete type.
>   . . .

Basically, as long as a type `S` is known to be of class type, the construct `S::*` is well-formed.

So you could even have this:

```
int main()
{
    struct S;
    cout << IsClass<S>::value; // still prints 1
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> What I don't understand is **why picking `int` as `X` works**, even if we test IsClass<> with a struct S that has no members at all (It also works for class types having a member other than int)

It does not have to be `int`, as it just performs its role as a *placeholder*.
You can replace that with `double` or `char` and see the same result coming.

It doesn't matter at all whether the given class type `T` does have a member function, because what `IsClass` tries to see is just that expression:

```
X Y::*
```

is **well-formed**.

This is just like you don't need an actual function definition (non-member function) merely to declare a type of pointer to that function as follows:

```
int main()
{
    // It doesn't matter whether there's a function int (*)(int, int, int) indeed because it's just merely a declaration
    using FuncP = int (*)(int, int, int);
    FuncP P;
}
```